# Make properties not modifiable in SharePoint library with PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I would like to make the fields not editable in all forms. My issue is that when I click on a document, I can edit and save properties.

I'm trying to modify a Library form created with Power Apps.

For this I created a copy of my FormScreen and its form.
I have then :

1. FormScreen_Edit with the following form SharePointForm_Edit
2. FormScreen_View with the following form SharePointForm_View

[image]

Display model for SharePoint_Edit is Modify and display model for Sharepoint_View is display

I also modified the SharePointIntegration part.

[image]

Comment: You don't want to allow users to modify the "Name" (Nom) of documents?

Comment: it's very weird but i'm asked to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint library
2. Select one document
3. Click on **Properties** from command bar at the top
4. Click on Edit columns dropdown & select **Customize with Power Apps**.
5. It will load the properties form in Power Apps (It may take some time)
6. In Power Apps studio, from tree view at the left click on **SharePointForm1** control
7. Set **DefaultMode** property to **View**
8. Click on **File** --> Save --> Publish to SharePoint

[image]

**Output**: Non-editable properties form

[image]

---

Even if you don't allow users to edit the properties from form, user can still edit properties from **Edit in grid view** or **Details pane**.

To avoid that, you can disable this functionalities by following this steps:

1. Go to SharePoint library
2. Click on **Settings** (gear icon) at the top
3. Select **Library settings**
4. Click on **Advanced settings**
5. On Advanced settings page, select **No** for **Quick property editing**
6. Scroll at the bottom of page & click **OK**

[image]

Comment: thanks Ganesh ! it helped me a lot. In fact it solved the issue.

Comment: you write faster than i upvote and accept as an answer :))