# Display Customize SharePoint Document Library Form directly

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have customize SharePoint document library form using power apps. However that form is displayed only when user click "edit all" after uploading a document.

[image]

How to turn off the details pane entirely and open the customized form directly by default after uploading a document without additional step of clicking "Edit all" in properties pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot customize the details pane using Power Apps, you can only customize the "Properties" forms of document library.

Here's what you can do in SharePoint online:

A. Disable editing of metadata from details pane and quick edit from library settings.

B. Customize Properties form using Power Apps and use below steps to open the form:

1. Go to SharePoint library
2. Select one document
3. Click on **Properties** from command bar at the top or from context menu (...)

For more information, check my answer at: [Make properties not modifiable in SharePoint library with PowerApps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293954/make-properties-not-modifiable-in-sharepoint-library-with-powerapps/293956#293956)

---

If you want to open Properties form directly from library view, you can use JSON formatting with `editProps` row action.

**Documentation**: [JSON formatting - CustomRowAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#customRowAction)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

To have the editable version of a form open in the library when a user opens properties:

In **PowerApps**, update **SharePointIntegration > Advanced > OnView** from *ViewForm(SharePointForm1)* to *EditForm(SharePointForm1)*

[image: Screencap of PowerApps Form window]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/sharepoint-form-integration